# Paging not Working Correctly in asp Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding an ASP Repeater from List & trying to add paging in the repeater. Each Page would have 5 Rows. when The Page is Run, 5 items are visible fine but when I click on "2" link button, nothing is visible. When I again Click on "1" the items of Page 2 are visible.

I've gone through [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-using-repeater-control-in-asp-net-with-and-without-stored-procedure/) to implement Paging.

Here is my aspx Code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rp_Order" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rp_Order_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
       <table class="table table-responsive">
          <tr >
              <th style="width:20%;">Data</th>

          </tr>

    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>           
            <td>                
               
             
                 <h5 style="font-weight:bold; "><%# Eval("NewsSubject") %></h5>
                 <p><%# Eval("NewsDate") %></p>

              
                                    <img src="ImageHandler.ashx?newsid=<%# Eval("NewsID") %>" visible="<%#Eval("ImageAttachment")!=null && Eval("ImageAttachment").ToString()!=""? "true": "false" %>" class="images image-responsive myimg" />
                                   
                                 
                                    <p ><%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("NewsDescription").ToString()) %></p>
                        
                                  

                                   <iframe src="<%#GetUrl(Eval("youtubeurl").ToString()) %>" width="400" frameborder="0" visible="<%#Eval("youtubeurl")!=null? "true": "false" %>'"></iframe>  
                                
            </td>
             
          
           
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

         <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage"  
                        Style="padding: 8px; margin: 2px; background: lightgray; border: solid 1px #666; color: black; font-weight: bold"  
                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"><%# Container.DataItem %>  
                    </asp:LinkButton>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is my Cs Code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {                
                BindData();
            }
        }
        public void BindData()
        {
            List<tblLatestNew> lst_news = new List<tblLatestNew>();
            lst_news = obj_news.GetLatestNews();

            DataTable dtData = Utilities.ToDataTable(lst_news);
            PagedDataSource pdsData = new PagedDataSource();
            DataView dv = new DataView(dtData);
            pdsData.DataSource = dv;
            pdsData.AllowPaging = true;
            pdsData.PageSize = 5;
            if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
                pdsData.CurrentPageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
            else
                pdsData.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
            if (pdsData.PageCount > 1)
            {
                Repeater1.Visible = true;
                ArrayList alPages = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 1; i <= pdsData.PageCount; i++)
                    alPages.Add((i).ToString());
                Repeater1.DataSource = alPages;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Repeater1.Visible = false;
            }
            rp_Order.DataSource = pdsData;
            rp_Order.DataBind();
        }
        protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["PageNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            BindData();
        }
```

Please Help me resolving this!
Currently my table has 7 Rows, so Page 1 should have 5 rows and Page 2 must have 2 Rows

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PagedDataSource requires a page index, which starts at zero for page 1. When you change the page in `Repeater1_ItemCommand` the command argument is the page number, not the page index.

To get the page index just change your code in  `Repeater1_ItemCommand` so that you subtract 1 from whatever number is passed in via `e.CommandArgument`, that way the proper page will display

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["PageNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
            BindData();
        }
```